# CAN-utils and socket can

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, socketcan, canutils

Am running Ubuntu 15.0 and trying desperately to get can-utils to run with all kinds of (USB) devices but with no luck at all.

When setting up  slcan and running candump or cansniffer i would expect at least something but nope, no incoming data at all.

The devices im trying to use are Ebay cables...

- Blue VAGCOM 401.9
- Black VAG K+CAN
- MPPS 13 (chiptuning)

I have  disassembled the MPPS cable, and it seems it has genuine hardware (not china clones) like: NXP SJA1000T, MCP2551 and it also has another chip one labelled as [c8051f380 (pdf link)](https://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/C8051F38x.pdf)

Unfortunately none of these interfaces reveal CAN data.
The can-utils is still a new tool for me so i probably (hopefully!) am missing some important steps, but if not i really cant see why none of these would not work... at all.

On top of that i do have MCP2551 transceiver, MCP2515 and a MCP2562FD controllers, but i dont have crystals nor caps to assemble my own interface, which i preferably would like.
I did try just for fun, FTD232RL (sparkfun one) with MCP2551 and sure i got data on OSX Coolterm, but yeah... thats was not much for fun since i did not have any controlled in the chain. This was the main reason i took apart the MPPS to see if it contains 16Mhz crystal + caps which i could take and use on my own setup. But when i saw which chips are used in this device, i thouhgt there must be some kind of possibility to get can-utils to work with it.

So to sum up... has anyone tested MPPS13 cable or any other china cable ? Since Linux and Kernels ans such are still a bit advanced for me, i cant really find any decent / proper setup for can-utils and all these drivers that need to be setup. And with desperation ive tried to run pretty much all terminal commands ive come across in hope to get something to work (stupid i know, but desperation is overwhelming). I wanted to test this all on rPI as well, since there are tons of pages available for the topic... but of course my PI has retired.

Comment: I've used candump with success with Peak PCAN-USB adapters. It uses a proprietary driver, not slcan, though. However, the usage of both drivers might be similar, so I can share the steps I've used to debug my own setup. In my case, there are some additional steps to bring the interface up, configure and verify the generated interface ID (e.g. can0). The following link (http://www.fischl.de/usbtin/linux_can_socketcan/) describes a process similar to what I've done, but for slcan. Perhaps it can be of some help.

Comment: What specific steps did you perform from the moment the device was plugged up to the point where you ran candump? Have you verified by any other mean that the device was recognized and that the CAN interface was brought up?

Answer (score 0):

I  might not have a real solution to your solution, but this setup works for me at least.

I use a "Kvaser Leaf Lite HS" usb-can interface with socket can on ubuntu 14.04.

I use the following setup:

`sudo modprobe can
sudo modprobe can_raw
sudo ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 50000 restart-ms 1000`

But strange thing happen if you add a second "Kvaser Leaf Lite HS" usb-can interface.

for a virtual  virtual device:

`sudo modprobe vcan
sudo ip link add dev vcan0 type vcan
sudo ip link set up vcan0`